# Por que me sale este error al momento de ejecutar?

Tags: sql-server

Itento crear la tabla de hechos
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 52
Conflicto de tipos de operandos: int es incompatible con time

```
  create table Hechos_Ordenes
( id_Lugar int,
  id_Clientes int,
  id_Productos int,
  FECHAKEY int,
  Sales smallint,
  Discount time,
  Profit float
 )

 insert into Hechos_Ordenes
 select l.id_Lugar, c.id_Clientes, p.id_Productos, t.FECHAKEY, count(s.Sales), count(s.Discount), count(s.Profit) 
 from SupermartG s, Dimension_Lugar l, Dimension_Productos p, Dimension_Clientes c, Dimension_Tiempo t
 where l.City=s.City and l.State=s.State and l.Region=s.Region and
       p.Sub_Category=s.Sub_Category and  p.Category=s.Category and
       c.Customer_Name=s.Customer_Name and
       t.fecha=s.Order_Date
group by l.id_Lugar, c.id_Clientes, p.id_Productos, t.FECHAKEY
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es la estructura de las tablas origen y la tabla destino del insert? COnsidera incluir las sentencias DDL (los CREATE TABLE, pues) para saber qué estás intentando insertar y dónde. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Por favor no uses los comentarios ni el campo de respuesta para dar información

Answer (score 0):

discount es de valor int y no puede entrar en un time, en todo caso tendrías que hacer una conversión en tu tabla, mas no en el select.

```sql
alter table Hechos_Ordenes alter column Discount int
```

y me parece que te estás equivocando también con el valor de tu fechakey, esa si que debería de ser time o mejor datetime para las posibles conversiones futuras.

```sql
alter table Hechos_Ordenes alter column FECHAKEY datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

En la tabla creada has definido el campo **Discount** como `time`.
En cambio en el `insert` que estás haciendo utilizas un `SUM` y eso devuelve un `integer`.

El error te está diciendo que *no puedes almacenar un valor `int` en un campo `time`*.

Si lo que quieres es sumar tiempos, tal vez podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

1. Convertir a minutos (integer)
2. Realizar el SUM (suma minutos)
3. Finalmente volver a convertirlo a time (horas:minutos)